# Building basic terminal with Python and change directory function isn't changing directory

Tags: python

cd function isn't changing directory for some reason! Whenever I use is on my terminal, it temporarly changes the directory, when i move to next command, action gets to be undone.

```
import os
import pathlib
from os.path import join

path = os.getcwd()


# DONE
def ls():
    os.listdir(path)
    print(os.listdir(path))


def pwd():
    print(os.getcwd())


def touch(file_name):
    fp = open(join(path, file_name), 'a')
    fp.close()


def rm(file_name):
    file = pathlib.Path(join(path, file_name))
    file.unlink()


def cd(file_name):
    os.chdir(join(path, file_name))


while True < 100:
    dirName = input()
    cmd = dirName.split(" ")[0]

    if cmd == "ls":  # DONE
        ls()
    elif cmd == "pwd":  # DONE
        pwd()
    elif cmd == "cd":  # DONE
        file_name = dirName.split(" ")[1]
        cd(file_name)
        print(os.getcwd())
    elif cmd == "touch":  # DONE
        file_name = dirName.split(" ")[1]
        touch(file_name)
    elif cmd == "rm":  # DONE
        file_name = dirName.split(" ")[1]
        rm(file_name)
    elif cmd == 'cd':  # DONE
        file_name = dirName.split(" ")[1]
        cd(file_name)
        print(pwd(file_name))
    else:
        print("Command not found!")
```

The problem is with the cd function, it's not working!

```
def cd(file_name):
    os.chdir(join(path, file_name))
```

It is expected that the cd function change directory.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how you set the initial value of `path` to `os.getcwd` and then you use it in the `cd` function.

This won't work like the `cd` command for every input because you can only access files and folders inside `path`.

What inputs have you tried?